# Make arbitrary DOM element a component container in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dom, dynamic

Scenario: in an Angular 2 app some elements are added to the DOM tree with jQuery, to display some dynamic content.

I'd like to replace some of them with actual Angular components. It would be better to apply directives to them, but AFAIK you cannot instance directives dynamically.

I know how to instance components at runtime, but after playing with the Renderer I can't find a way of inserting them into jQuery-generated elements.

How could that be done?

The solution must work for Angular >= 2 and < 4, but if it was possible only on 4+, a solution for it would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but in Angular2+ you can use selectors and implement it into HTML tags. Let's say you have a  details component, at the beginning      @Component({
      selector: 'app-details',
      templateUrl: './details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
    })
Then in any HTML file you want you can put <app-details></app-details> and display the component

Comment: Thanks, but Angular won't catch the addition of the element to the DOM to make a true component out of it. It would be a "dead" element. Component selectors are only matched with tags on the template.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? Just ran into the exact same use case :)